# Keycloak is automatically changing certificate

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, certbot, keycloak

I'm using Keycloak Quay 22.0.3 with docker-compose behind a Nginx reverse proxy but I have some troubles due an automatic replace of my certificate generated with certbot.

My certificate generated with certbot it's completely fine, it says it will expire after 3 months from now, (Issued by) its CN is R3 and its Organization is Let's Encrypt (as the others domains).

Once I start up the docker-compose it **may** use the correct certificate for *t* time and it uses HTTPS, then, suddenly, it gets replaced by one that I didn't generate, (Issued by) CN Cisco Umbrella Secondary SubCA ams-SG and Organization Cisco and (Issued to) Organization Cisco Systems, Inc. while it was blank before, and of course, connection is not private anymore (`NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`).

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  keycloak:
    container_name: "keycloak"
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.3
    environment:
      KC_DB: mysql
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:mysql://database_container:3306/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: username
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: kc_admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: kc_admin_password
      KC_HOSTNAME: keycloak.hostname.com
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: "false"
    ports:
      - "8443:8443"
    volumes:
      - /keycloak/certs/fullchain.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt
      - /keycloak/certs/privkey.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.key
    command:
      start --https-certificate-file=/etc/x509/https/tls.crt --https-certificate-key-file=/etc/x509/https/tls.key --hostname-strict=false
    networks:
      - my_network

networks:
  my_network:
    name: my_network
    external: true
```

And this is my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    server_name www.keycloak.hostname.com keycloak.hostname.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://ip_address:8443/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
        proxy_buffer_size 256k;
        proxy_buffers 4 512k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 512k;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/keycloak.hostname.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/keycloak.hostname.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.keycloak.hostname.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = keycloak.hostname.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name www.keycloak.hostname.com keycloak.hostname.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

The certificates used in docker-compose are `/etc/letsencrypt/live/keycloak.hostname.com/*` and with 655 permission.

Edit

I forgot to mention that the certificate issued by Cisco Umbrella is valid from 09-17-2023 to 09-22-2023.

Comment: Umbrella? Your organization is obviously using it. What is the relevant configuration?

Comment: @GregAskew I'm hosting it on Oracle OCI, I don't know how to retrieve it.
But my question is: why do other service not have this kind of problem? They keep the issued certificate without replacing it by the time

Comment: You obviously have Umbrella in your environment. It's an expensive product that you have to pay for. It doesn't miracle certificates from nowhere.

Comment: @GregAskew I updated my question, since I forgot to mention the duration of the issued certificate. Anyway, I haven't paid for such service since my plan doesn't involve paid services (always-free tier). I checked the generated certificate after running `certbot` command and the issuer is Let's Encrypt, not Umbrella.